# Qgis python: no interaction with Map Canvas

Tags: qgis, python, mapcanvas

I've created a simple python script to load and show two layers and zoom to the first one. It looks like the script doesn't run the last 4 lines after I uncomment'print lyr1'. Anyway the map canvas is not changing.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

lyr1= QgsVectorLayer("C:\\Area1.shp", "Layer 1", "ogr")
lyr2= QgsVectorLayer("C:\\Area2.shp", "Layer 2", "ogr")
reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
reg.addMapLayers([lyr1, lyr2])

#print lyr1

rect = QgsRectangle(lyr1.extent())
rect.scale(5)
canvas.setExtent(rect)
canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: Your script works fine for me when running it in the python console and as a script. Where are you running it from? Try commenting out `rect.scale(5)` as that zooms the canvas out quite a bit. And are you wanting your script to _show_ the layers (i.e. turn their visibility on)?

Comment: I run the script from the python console within Qgis. Uncommenting rect.scale(5) offers no solution. Yes I want to see all the layers.

Comment: After the `reg.addMapLayers([lyr1, lyr2])` line, use something like `for layer in [lyr1, lyr2]:` then indent next line and use `iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)`. This should _check_ the loaded layers.

Comment: Nope still the same. Both layers are visible, also without setLayerVisible. That's not the problem. There is also no problem if there is allready a layer in the legend/map.

Comment: Yes, I forgot there's a default setting in QGIS which shows loaded layers automatically so you're right, no need for the loop. Are you sure the last 4 lines are not being run? Did you test this by using `print rect` or `print canvas` at the end and see if it prints?

Comment: `print rect` returns `<qgis._core.QgsRectangle object at 0x000000003691D2F0>` So it runs the last 4 lines. But still the canvas does not zoom to layer 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40378/discussion-between-steven-and-joseph).